# Showing that $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty f(x - k) < \infty$ a.e. $x\in\mathbb{R}, f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $f\in L^1\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$ be a fixed point s.t. $|f(x - k)| < \infty$ for every $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. I am trying to show that then $S(f,x) := \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty f(x - k) < \infty$. I am suspecting that some intergal-series convergence test could be helpful or some manipulation of the $L1$-norm of $f$. Since we know that $f$ vanishes at $\infty$, no good convergence test comes to my mind unless we modify $f$ somehow: we know that $f(x - k) \to 0, |k|\to\infty$, but $f$ need not be monotonically decreasing w.r.t. $|k| = 1, 2, 3,\dots$. As for the second approach, the $L1$ norm of $f$, my idea was to bound $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(y)|dy$ below by $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty |f(x - k)|$ with something like

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(y)|dy = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \int_{k}^{k+1}|f(y)|dy \geq \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \int_{[k,k+1]\cap \{y:|f(y)| \leq |f(x - k)|\}}|f(y)|dy$$

but I don't see how you can massage a uniform non-zero coefficient for each of the summands of the series.

Comment: For every $x$? Certainly false.

Comment: @geetha290krm True, it is now fixed.

Comment: @OliverDíaz I think it does. If I am not mistaken the answer by geetha290krm is a bit similar.

Comment: @EpsilonAway:  It is a classic theme in Fourier analysis (Abel summation). Not surprised that there are older duplicates to your posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only prove convergence for almost all $x$. You cannot fix $x$ in advance. For a counter example take $f=1$ on the integers and $0$ elsewhere with $x=0$.

Hint: $\int_j^{j+1}\sum_k |f(x-k)|dx=\sum_k \int_{j-k}^{j-k+1} |f(y)|dy\leq \int_{\mathbb R} |f(y)|dy<\infty$ so the series converges absolutely for almost all $x$ in $(j,j+1)$. This is true for every $j$.

[For all $x$ should be changed to 'for almost all $x$' in your question].

Comment: Edit - spelling.

Comment: @K.defaoite What good does $\int_j^{j+1}\sum_k |f(x - k)|dx$ do to us when the $x$ should be a fixed value? That is, why $S(f,x)\leq\int_j^{j+1}\sum_k |f(x - k)|dx$?

Comment: $x$ cannot be fixed in advance because the result is not even true for every fixed $x$. @EpsilonAway

Comment: @geetha290krm Sorry, I somehow misread who answered originally. Regarding the hint, I have edited the question. So let us only focus on those $x$ with the property that $|f(x - k)| < \infty, \forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$. In this case how could we show that the series converges?

Comment: You cannot prove it for such $x$ also.

Comment: @EpsilonAway See my answer now.